# Doesn't display field with array in object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I use the Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API.

But I found issue with object as request model.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] PagedRequest request)
```

And the class

```
 public class PagedRequest : PagedRequest
    {
        public int[] LocationIds { get; set; }
        public SomeType Type { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't see location field in test modal window in parameters.
If I pass field in action - it is work rigth

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't understand the question.
But maybe you have a namespace problem? Your example class has the same name as the parentclass. So the first included namespace in your cs-file determine the object.
Maybe you should use the following instead:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] YourNamespace.PagedRequest request)
```